# Как начать разрабатывать android приложение с последующей покупкой полной версии

Tags: android, монетизация

Есть идея для приложения. Хочу создать android приложение с некоторым бесплатным функционалом. Для  получения получения полной версии со всей функциональностью надо будет оплатить полную версию. Как это можно будет реализовать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Очень много ресурсов есть в открытом интернете на эту тему. https://habr.com/ru/company/vk/blog/513724/

Comment: Вот тут [полный путеводитель](https://github.com/skydoves/android-developer-roadmap) с чего начать и что за чем делать

Comment: В Google Play Store есть соответствующие настройки.
Но я бы начал просто с бесплатной версии,
а на монетизации доп. функционала сосредоточился бы потом,
когда прорисуется хоть какая-то востребованность Вашего приложения.
(а это отдельный челлендж)
Поскольку заливать новые версии Вашего приложения все-равно придется неоднократно,
то просто какая-то очередная версия будет с доп. платным функционалом.